# Pandas ignoring cells with " and ,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a semicolon-delimited pandas DataFrame with all dtypes of object. Within some of the cells the string value can have ", a comma (,), or both (ex. TES"T_ING,_VALUE). I am then querying the DF using df.query based on some condition to get a subset of the DataFrame but the rows that have the pattern described in the example are being omitted completely but the remaining rows are being returned just fine. Another requirement is that I need to match all " within the text with a closing quote as well but applying a lambda to replace " with "" is also not being done properly. I have tried several methods and they are listed below

Problem 1:

```
pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter=';')
pd.read_csv("file.csv", delmiter=';', thousands=',')
pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter=";", escapechar='"')
pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter=";", encoding='utf-8')
```

All of the above fail to load the data in question.

Problem 2:
Input: TES"T_ING,_VALUE to TES""T_ING,_VALUE
I have tried:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace('"', '""')
```

which doesn't do anything.

What exactly is going on? I haven't been able to find any questions tackling this particular type of issue anywhere.

Appreciate your help in advance.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't provide some mockup data due to sensitivity but here is some fake data that illustrates the issue

The following is a sample of how the csv structure

Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4;Column5\n
TES"T_ING,_VALUE;Col2Value;Col3Value;Col4Value;Col5Value\n
Col1value;TES"T_ING,_VALUE2;Col3Value;Col4Value;Col5Value\n

I have tried utilizing quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL/QUOTE_NONNUMERIC and quotechar='"' when loading in the df but the result ends up being
Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4;Column5\n
"TES"T_ING,_VALUE;Col2Value;Col3Value;Col4Value;Col5Value";;;;\n
"Col1value;TES"T_ING,_VALUE2;Col3Value;Col4Value;Col5Value";;;;\n

So it interprets the whole row as value in column 1 rather than actually splitting on the ; and applying the quoting to only column1. Truthfully I can iterate through each row in the df and maybe do a split and load the remaining values into their respective column but the CSV is quite large so this operation would take sometime. The subset of the data the user queries on is supposed to be returned from an endpoint (this part is already working).

Comment: could you provide sample data ->https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, @AtanasAtanasov I didn't provide any test data because of sensitivity issues but I tried to mock some up. I apologize!

Comment: I am pretty sure this is homework. I doubt the data is sensitive. Pls re-read your lesson and the answers will come to you

Comment: Definitely not homework but I am posting my solution below

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved utilizing pd.apply and utilizing a custom function to process each record.

```
df = pd.read_csv("csv_file.csv", delimiter=';', escapechar='\\')

def mapper(record):
    if ';' in record['col1']:
        content = record['col1'].split(';')
    if len(content) == num_columns:
        if '"' in content[0]:
            content[0] = content[0].replace('"', '""')
        record['col1'] = content[0]
        # repeat for remaining columns


processed = df.apply(lambda x: mapper(x), axis=1)
```